# Deriving center of mass coordinates of a uniform semicircular disc without using an area integral

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

In how many ways can I derive centre of mass coordinates for a uniform semicircular disc?

One way my friend told me was to use the areal mass density (which gave correct coordinates), but I attempted it in following way:

$ \frac{dm}{d \theta} =  \frac{M}{ \pi} $
Taking Origin to be the center of the complete circle made by it, with straight edge of semicircular disc lying on the x axis.
M is total mass.
Now,

$X_{cm}=\frac{1}{M} \int{x dm}$

and,

$Y_{cm}=\frac{1}{M} \int{y dm}$

And if R is the radius then,

$X_{cm}=\frac{1}{M} \int_{R}^{-R}{x dm}$

and,

$Y_{cm}=\frac{1}{M} \int_{0}^{R}{y dm}$

So what I did was to convert x to Rcosθ and y to Rsinθ.

And, I did got $X_{cm}=0$ but couldn't get $Y_{cm}=\frac{4R}{3 \pi}$ .

So can you please help me spot the mistake and also tell other ways to achieve the same?

Comment: You most likely made a mistake in getting your integral to the right form with the coordinate transformations and with the infinitesimal elements. Since there are many ways this could go wrong, it is hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: @AaronStevens So, are you saying that the method by which I attempted to find the coordinates is a correct one but there can be a mistake in the integral solving??

Comment: There is most likely a mistake in setting up your integral. You have to do more than just change $y$ to $R\sin\theta$ and change $dm$ to $\frac{M}{\pi}d\theta$ as well as your limits. That integral is just considering $y$ values on the outer edge of your disk. Not over the entire area.

Comment: If you want to do it this way, you need to determine the y - COM of each section covering angle $d\theta$ first, and then add all of those up

Comment: But would did something wrong boì

Comment: How many ways can you parametrize a semicircular disk? Well, all the ways are a variation of two base methods. a) Cartesian coordinates, and b) Polar coordinates.

Comment: @AaronStevens now I understand where I went wrong, I was finding for outer edge not the whole semi disk, but I still can't figure out why does not that method work

Comment: It does work, you just have to do it right. I will post an answer eventually when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the integral $\int_0^\pi R\sin\theta\ \text d\theta$ only considers y-coordinates along the outer edge of the disk. If you don't want your solution to involve the typical area integral, we are going to have to be more creative.

By using the idea of an "angular density" 
$$\frac{\text d m}{\text d \theta}=\frac{M}{\pi}$$
what we are conveying here is the idea of infinitesimal mass elements with a mass $\text d m=\frac{M}{\pi}\text d \theta$ that represent a "wedge" of the disk with area $\frac12R^2\text d \theta$. Therefore, what we can do is determine the center of mass of each infinitesimal wedge, treat each wedge as its own "particle" with mass $\text d m$ located at its center of mass, and then find the center of mass of this new configuration. A picture of the idea is shown below, where the left shows the wedges, and the right shows the new configuration of "equivalent" particles:
[image]

Since this is a "homework-like" problem, I will not give you a complete solution here, but I will give some hints. By symmetry, we know that the center of mass of each wedge is going to have the same radial location $r_w$, therefore,the y-coordinate of each wedge is given by
$$y_w=r_w\sin\theta$$

Furthermore, $r_w$ will not have a $\theta$ dependence, therefore, our final integral for the y-coordinate of the center of mass of the semi-disk will be
$$y_{com}=\frac1M \int y_w\ \text d m=\frac{r_w}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\ \text d \theta=\frac{2r_w}{\pi}$$
since we already know what the answer is $\left(y_{com}=\frac{4R}{3\pi}\right)$, it must be that $r_w=\frac23R$.

I will leave it to you to figure out how to show the the radial position of the center of mass of an infinitesimal wedge is given by $r_w=\frac23R$. But I can say it does end up working out to be this.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Stevens !!, Actually I was confused in why simply using angular density could not work for a disc, the doubt which you cleared in the first para of your answer.

Comment: @Adi Yeah it was fun to think about for me, so I might have gotten carried away haha